# sync call from process with many incoming msgs

Tags: erlang, workflow, ipc

Need to implement sync call from proces which receives many incoming messages from other processes. Problem in distinguish - when msg in return to call arrived. Do i need to spawn additional process for extracting msgs from queue into buffer while return msg not encountered and then send it to main process and after it every else accepted.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood your question.

Comment: Assuming I've understood correctly your question - but I doubt it -, you have several processes sending random messages to a single server, which needs to collect (and maybe process) the messages until it receives a special message, in which case, it replies to the caller. Is that what you mean?

Comment: my process is a mediator between clients and distributed db nodes. Eventually clent can demand replication between nodes. During replication no one request to db can be processed, they must be buffered and processed after replication finished. Replication completion trigger sending message to mediator, but in queue of mediator a lot of messages. How mediator will know that he receive special message about replication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to use a reference as a token for replication:

```
 replicate() ->
    {ok, Token} = db:ask_replicate(...),
    receive
       {replication_completed, Token} ->
             ok
    end
```

where `Token` is created with a call to `make_ref()`. Since no other message will match `Token`, you are safe. Other messages will be placed in the mailbox for later scrutiny.

However, the above solution does not take process crashes into account. You need a monitor on the DB server as well. The simplest way to get the pattern right is to let the mediator be a `gen_server`. Alternatively, you can read a chapter in LearnYouSomeErlang: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/what-is-otp#the-basic-server look at the synchronous call in the `kitty_server`.

Comment: Man, now i at chapter 11 in Cesarini and Thompson, next one is "OTP behaviors", then i definitely read provided link. Thanks.)))

Comment: Now i implement additional thread, which job is filter messages, with it i workaround consistency of mwssage queue and pop needed message from middle of the queue. You know, between call to ask_replicate and replication_completed arrived i can get tonns of messages from another process.